# Running java code in a batch file if the SYSDATE is a SUNDAY

Tags: batch-file

I have a java file TestOutput.java that we need to run only on Sundays. We also have a DOS based file copy command that need to run only on Sunday. How can this be achieved?
The batch file has some parts that need to run every day, and some that runs only on Sunday.

It has to do the following in the batch file:

```
REM This part runs every day
copy E:\Data\output1.psv S:\Output\output1.psv
...
...
...
REM This part runs on Sunday only
IF (DAY of sysdate=='SUNDAY')
    java TestOutput
    copy E:\Data\output2.psv S:\Output\output2.psv
END IF
```

please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is locale independent.

```
set "dayOfWeek="
for /f "skip=1" %%A in ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek') do if not defined dayOfWeek set "dayOfWeek=%%A"
::0=Sunday, 1=Monday,... 6=Saturday
if "%dayOfWeek%"=="0" (
  REM Sunday processing goes here
)
```

Comment: upvoted, but is Sunday not 0 as per [this MS Note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?  It certainly is on my machine...

Comment: I changed the "%dayOfWeek%"=="2" so it will run today and changed set "dayOfWeek=%%A" ::0=Sunday,1=Monday,2=Tuesday,3=Wednesday,4=Thursday,5=Friday,6=Saturday to include all days of week. It still does not go into the loop.

Comment: @Ram - If the test is in the same block of code that sets the variable, then you need to use delayed expansion: `!dayOfWeek!`. Delayed expansion is enabled by issuing `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`.

Comment: Still no luck: setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

set "dayOfWeek="
for /f "skip=1" %%A in ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek') do if not defined "dayOfWeek" set "dayOfWeek=%%A" ::0=Sunday,1=Monday,2=Tuesday,3=Wednesday,4=Thursday,5=Friday,6=Saturday 
if "!dayOfWeek!"=="2" (

copy E:\Output\output1.psv E:\Output\output2.psv

)

Comment: @Ram - OMG, I'm sorry. I had a bug that a noob might make, but I should have known better. I had quotes in my IF DEFINED that needed to be removed. All fixed now. Delayed expansion is not needed if your code is like mine. It is only needed if there are parentheses enclosing the FOR statement and the following IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Windows Task Scheduler.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this has some pieces that has to run every day. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in ('echo %DATE%') do if %%a==Sun (
REM your code here
)
```